# Connotation of the word "sprezzatura "

Tags: meaning, nouns, connotation

According to Wikipedia, *[sprezzatura](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprezzatura)* means

> a certain nonchalance, so as to conceal all art and make whatever one does or says appear to be without effort and almost without any thought about it.

But has the word taken on a meaning more related to just "indifference" as opposed to the one above?

Comment: What evidence do you have that that might be the case?

Comment: It's an unusual, rare word.

Comment: @Carlo_R. My comment is hardly indifferent or nonchalant. If there is no evidence, it's safe to say that the word has not taken on another meaning. Is the community really being asked to do the OP's research? What prompted the question in the first place?

Comment: SprezzaWHAT'Sa? I think I'm way behind some curve here. I wonder if there is any evidence that any human being has actually _said_ this word in conversation, yet you're already asking if it has _changed_??

Comment: I don't know, user44557, but there is an easier word to use, and it conveys pretty much the same thing as sprezzatura, and that is "artless" (or artlessness).  Artless: not artificial; natural; simple; uncontrived: "artless beauty"; "artless charm" (http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/artless?s=t).

Comment: Now I have a word for my behavior while I was enjoying a run of strikes in my 3rd game of bowling ever -- the run came to 6.  I was all like "nothing's happening here!" in the hope that I wouldn't inadvertantly jinx the run.  But can you use that in a sentence?

Comment: I've just checked, and this user apparently hasn't even visited this site since 20 mins after asking the question!

Answer (score 2):

Studied nonchalance? Only *apparent* indifference.

> The magician showed much **sprezzatura** as he performed his act with ease. It is as though it comes to him naturally (UD)

[Alisa Brough, 2006](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=JDRRNwAACAAJ&dq=sprezzatura&hl=en):

> Elizabeth Tudor, Queen of England, weaves the courtier[alpha]s strategy of **sprezzatura** throughout her public orations in order to help her identify with her audience of courtiers, scholars, and politicians.

[emphasis mine]

---

[UPDATE]

> … R. J. Clements has pointed to a contextual – or associative and lexical – field of meaning for *sprezzatura:* "Within lightness of touch, easiness of manner, effortless deftness, the semantic value of *sprezzatura* is somewhere in the area." … *sprezzatura* upholds the presumption of a righteous superiority vis-a-vis anything different. 
>   (Giancarlo Maiorino, *The Portrait of Eccentricity: Arcimboldo and the Mannerist Grotesque*, p.19 from [GoogleBooks](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=XYJbHJJ42d4C&pg=PA19&dq=sprezzatura&hl=en&sa=X&ei=lxhpUvjEKYKOrQfHkYGoBw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=sprezzatura&f=false))